# Design pattern for Core Data default entries

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm planning a new ios app and am not sure of what is the best way to set up a start list for a tableView on first app start. The app uses Core Data (more precisely Magical Record). Should I use some kind of (p)list (dictionary) which gets imported or should I just hard code the default entries like when the user adds something through a formula? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a load of arguments for and against all different ways of doing this.

Personally I prefer just to hard code all the default entries (if there aren't thousands of them obviously).

Comment: Well, actually there are 270 ;) But thank you, I'll hard code them then. Just wanted to be sure there wasn't any obvious way other people use every day.

Comment: I've actually used a spreadsheet to create the repetitive code before. Might be easier/quicker for you.

Comment: Ok that sounds a lot easier, how did you do that?

Comment: I worked out what the repeating code was (i.e. [[MyObject alloc] initWithEntity:@"SomeEntityName" insertIntoContext:context name:@"someName" number:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt]]) etc... then I took my data which was actually in a spreadsheet. And just used functions within the spreadsheet to concatenate the various component parts so that I had the correct function to create all the various objects. Then I can copy/paste them into the code.